# "The data couldn't be read because it is in the incorrect format" Login system for IOS using swift and a MySQL database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, xcode

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, if anyone understands I would appreciate your help.
I might be putting values at the wrong place...
I use php to convert data from MySQL to a JSON format.

Php and swift below.

login.php file (http://zzzway.com/appMango/login.php)

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");

if(isset($_POST['loginbutton']))
{
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli("123", "123", "123", "123");



    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);    
    }
    $email = $_POST["email"]; 
    $password = $_POST["password"]; 
    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM `zusers` WHERE `cEmail` = '$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
    {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);    
    $hash = password_verify($password, $row['cPassword']);
    if ($hash == 1)
        {

        session_set_cookie_params(0);
        session_start();

        $firstname = $row['cFirstname'];
        $lastname = $row['cLastname'];
        $email = $row['cEmail'];
        $numpts = $row['NumPts'];
        $numuser = $row['NumUser'];

        if($row !=1)
            {
                $erreur=0;
            }
                else
            {
                $erreur=1;
            }

       echo '{  "erreur":'.$erreur.', "nom":"'.$firstname.'", "id":"'.$numuser.'", "pseudo":"'.$email.'"  }';

        }
    }
}
?>
```

index.html(http://zzzway.com/appMango/login.php)

```
    <form action="login.php" class="login" method="post" autocomplete="on">


                <input  name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required>


                <input  name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" id="password" required>
                <input class="button border margin-top-5" type="submit" name="loginbutton" value="Connecter"><br>
</form>
```

swift Networking Service file

```
    import Foundation

enum MyResult<T, E: Error> {

    case success(T)
    case failure(E)
}

class NetworkingService {

    let baseUrl = "https://zzzway.com/appMango/"

    func handleResponse(for request: URLRequest,
                        completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                guard let unwrappedResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badResponse))
                    return
                }

                print(unwrappedResponse.statusCode)

                switch unwrappedResponse.statusCode {

                case 200 ..< 300:
                    print("success")

                default:
                    print("failure")
                }

                if let unwrappedError = error {
                    completion(.failure(unwrappedError))
                    return
                }

                if let unwrappedData = data {

                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: [])
                        print(json)

                        if let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: unwrappedData) {
                            completion(.success(user))

                        } else {
                            let errorResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse.self, from: unwrappedData)
                            completion(.failure(errorResponse))
                        }

                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func request(endpoint: String,
                 parameters: [String: Any],
                 completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl) else {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badUrl))
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        var components = URLComponents()

        var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

        for (key, value) in parameters {

            let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: String(describing: value))
            queryItems.append(queryItem)
        }

        components.queryItems = queryItems

        // username=kiloloco&password=pass123
        let queryItemData = components.query?.data(using: .utf8)

        request.httpBody = queryItemData
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        handleResponse(for: request, completion: completion)
    }

    func request(endpoint: String,
                 loginObject: Login,
                 completion: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl) else {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badUrl))
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        do {
            let loginData = try JSONEncoder().encode(loginObject)
            request.httpBody = loginData

        } catch {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badEncoding))
        }

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        handleResponse(for: request, completion: completion)
    }


}

enum NetworkingError: Error {
    case badUrl
    case badResponse
    case badEncoding
}
```

swift loginViewController file

```
    import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UITableViewController {

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    let alertService = AlertService()
    let networkingService = NetworkingService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    }

    @IBAction func didTapLoginButton() {

        guard
            let username = usernameTextField.text,
            let password = passwordTextField.text
            else { return }


//        formDataRequest(username: username, password: password)

        jsonRequest(cEmail: username, cPassword: password)
    }

    func formDataRequest(cEmail: String, cPassword: String) {
        let parameters = ["cEmail": cEmail,
                          "cPassword": cPassword]

        networkingService.request(endpoint: "/login.php", parameters: parameters) { [weak self] (result) in

            switch result {

            case .success(let user): self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: user)

            case.failure(let error):

                guard let alert = self?.alertService.alert(message: error.localizedDescription) else { return }
                self?.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    func jsonRequest(cEmail:String, cPassword: String) {

        let login = Login(cEmail: cEmail, cPassword: cPassword)

        networkingService.request(endpoint: "/login.php", loginObject: login) { [weak self] (result) in

            switch result {

            case .success(let user): self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: user)

            case.failure(let error):

                guard let alert = self?.alertService.alert(message: error.localizedDescription) else { return }
                self?.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let mainAppVC = segue.destination as? MainAppViewController, let user = sender as? User {

            mainAppVC.user = user
        }
    }
}
```

swift User file

```
    import Foundation

struct User: Decodable {
    let NumUser: Int
    let cFirstname: String
    let cEmail: String
    let cPassword: String

}
```

swift Login file

```
    import Foundation

struct Login: Encodable
{
    let cEmail: String
    let cPassword: String
}
```